# exporting data in spreadsheets from one computer to another via matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a GUI which will compare data (fluorescence intensities) stored in excel files for 2 volunteers. If I execute the GUI from some other PC, how can I transfer the data via MATLAB?

Is there any other method apart from using the client-server option?

Comment: What do you mean transfer data via MATLAB? MATLAB is not a comunication protocol. Do you want it transported via internet, USB, drone,...?

Comment: Transported via Internet, but is there is any way where in the medium be Matlab (since the data is just excel files).

Comment: Internet or local Network connection? In local network, the simple way is to create a shared folder, and read the file directly from the other computer.

Comment: I Think you should use CSV file format. CSV format is supported both by Excel and Matlab.